# Manually assign cases - omni channel supervisor not updated

Tags: queue, omnichannel, agentwork

I am having a challenge with a recent requirement from my support team. We implemented OmniChannel and AgentWork is being routed through Queues.

Their new requirement is this: When a Case is manually assigned to an agent through the change owner modal window in the Salesforce UI, the Case should show up in the "My work" tab of OmniChannel and be counted as part of their current capacity. Next to that the omni channel supervisor "Queues Backlog" *Total Waiting* number should be lowered with 1. And the *"Assigned Work"* should be updated with this manually assigned case. But this isn't happening when you assign a case manually which gives a wrong indication to supervisors.

I have managed to assign an AgentWork record to the User using this object and this is recognized in the "My work" tab via a flow.  I have built a record triggered Flow to create a `AgentWork` record when a case owner is manually changed from a Queue to an user with the `UserId` of the `AgentWork` set to the new case.OwnerId. Now this creates a new work item in the omni channel view under *"My work"*.
[image]

**The problem is**: I'm not able to set the `Queue` value on the `WorkAgent` object.

This results in that the queue backlog "Total waiting" and the Assigned Work isn't updated in the OmniChannel Supervisor.
[image: Number not updated]

Has anyone else been successful in this kind of requirement?

Comment: I think you may need to delete the PendingServiceRouting Record. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can play with an Omnichannel Flow to do the assignment and route the WorkItem in Omnichannel to the specified agent.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_route_to_specific_agent.htm&type=5